# Не работает получение имени vk open api

Tags: vkontakte-api

```
VK.init({
    apiId: 4850938
});

function authInfo(response) {    
    if(response.status=='connected') {  // если пользователь залогинен в ВК     
        if (typeof(response.session.user) == 'undefined') { // этого поля нет 
            //тогда, когда пользователь был залогинен ранее
            VK.Api.call('users.get', { uid: response.session.mid }, function(r) { 
                $('#VKInfo').html(r.response[0].first_name+' '+r.response[0].last_name); 
                $('#VKInfo').append('user_id: '+response.session.mid); });
        } else {
            // если авторизация прошла только что (от VK.Auth.login(authInfo);), то имя и фамилия уже будут в ответе   
            $('#VKInfo').html(response.session.user.first_name+' '+response.session.user.last_name);
            $('#VKInfo').append(.'user_id: '+response.session.mid);
        }

    } else {
        VK.Auth.login(authInfo); // опционально можем спалиться и вызвать всплывающее окно авторизации
    }
}

$(function() { VK.Auth.getLoginStatus(authInfo); }); // проверяем наличие входа в ВК, ответ отправляем в функцию обработчик
```

А в `<body>` следующее:

```
<span id="VKInfo"> </span>
```

Но в итоге в span ничего не приходит.

Comment: что мешает написать `console.log(r)` и посмотреть что в ответе приходит?

Comment: .........ну а вообще просто синтаксическая ошибка `.append(.'user_id: '` ......точка перед `'user_id`........... и это, кстати, можно было узнать также открыв банально консоль

Comment: Ни на что не повлияло, единственная ошибка в консоли: openapi.js?136:434 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of undefined(…)

Comment: Ой да ладно....уверен была она ошибка, стала другая...... и `VK.init` должен быть в `body`. Наверняка у вас где-нибудь в head всё висит

Comment: Да, в <head> была ошибка. А почему в <body>?

Comment: Оформите тогда ответ по body в качестве ответа, поставлю как правильный.